# Как хранить изображения в готовой базе SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть готовая база данных, необходимо в ней хранить изображения (Порядка 1000 картинок, около 40кб каждая). Рето Майер пишет, что лучше в базе хранить ссылки на картинки, а сами картинки отдельно. Но как я понял, готовые картинки в любом случае надо будет хранить где-то в приложении, например в assets, чтобы потом их можно было скопировать на SD карту. Хочется минимизировать размер приложения во внутренней памяти телефона. Как мне оптимизировать решение этой проблемы? Пока вижу 2 выхода, либо хранить в базе, либо в assets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Храните картинки на сервере(сайте). Есть например сайт [parse.com](https://parse.com/) специально сделанный для упрощения создания клиент-серверных мобильных приложений. Там можно хранить и картинки и бд и все что угодно.
Думаю это самое то если их 1000.
Если картинок мало, то можно положить и в assets или raw, но конечно смотря какого они разрешения, то бишь размера.

А хранение в базе картинок как бинарников врят ли решит проблему. База все равно копируется вместе с данными приложения в память, то бишь от ее разбухания никуда не деться. Не говоря уже о том, что готовые картинки врят ли стоит хранить в БД :)

Answer (score 2):

Храните картинки на сервере.

При запуске по надобности подгружаете картинки и складируете во внутреннюю или внешнюю память. Если работаете ещё и с базой, то можно там хранить ссылки на эти файлы физические.

Хранить пикчи в базе в BLOB'е - моветон.